# Resource 'appid or objectid' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-service-principal

I am trying to associate a claimmappingpolicy with a main service from the graph api:
[image]

I tried to the call with the object id and appid, but it is not working, the resource is not found, but the resource exits:
[image]

and the policy exist too:
[image]

why not find the service principal with the graph api ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the app registration, which means you are looking at ids of the Application object.
You need the service principal objectId instead.

You can click "Managed application in local directory" from the app registration or go to "Enterprise applications" and find your service principal from there (it has the same name).

Documentation: [Application and service principal objects in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals)